# Assign a cell a blank value instead of zero with =F

Tags: excel, zero, forecast

Here is my formula:

```
=IF('LBD Weigth Loss Tracking'!B6=ISBLANK('LBD Weigth Loss Tracking'!B6),"",'LBD Weigth Loss Tracking'!B6)
```

What I want is for the cell to be blank instead of zero but haven't found a way to do that.

The reason is because the table is used in a forecast chart and when the source cell is blank then the cell in the forecast sheet shows 0 causing the forecast to plummet to zero after the last valid value is entered.

This is for my weight loss tracking where I have a sheet with the raw data and then a sheet with the forecast chart/graph.

Thanks for any tips/hints

Comment: Chart data sources have an Hidden and Empty Cell Setting of "Connect data points with line". See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-empty-cells-null-N-A-values-and-hidden-worksheet-data-in-a-chart-a1ee6f0c-192f-4248-abeb-9ca49cb92274)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('LBD Weigth Loss Tracking'!B6),0,'LBD Weigth Loss Tracking'!B6)
```

Please check the name of the sheet you address as "weight" is not the same as "weigth" , note I have not changed the name in the example I gave you.

Comment: Thank you for catching my typo.  That didn't help with the chart which still has a vertical line to 0.

This is working better for me as now the cell shows a blank instead of 0.